# rsync using --files-from produces 'No such file or directory' error

Tags: linux, macos, directory, find, rsync

I'm using rsync with the --files-from option to copy a list of directories from a networked drive to my desktop. In this case I want to copy all directories named `tennis` or `football` (case insensitive). Though the directories exit, and I can `cp -a` all of them, the rsync command doesn't seem to be able to see them!

Here's the rsync command I'm trying to use:

`rsync --recursive --files-from=<(find /Volumes/GroupFolders -iname '*tennis*' -o -iname '*football*' | sed 's/ /\\ /g') / ./Desktop/new_folder/`

And I get this error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/Volumes/GroupFolders/2020/October/Tennis" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/38cf1d983f/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Here's the structure of the directories on the networked drive:

```
|-- 2020
|   |-- October
|   |   |-- Tennis
|   |   |-- Squash
|   |   |-- Yoga
|   |   |-- Running
|   |   |-- Bowling
|   |   `-- Shotput
|   `-- September
|       `-- Squash
`-- 2021
    |-- January
    |   |-- Racketball
    |   |-- Squash
    |   |-- Swimming
    |   |-- Handball
    |   |-- Baseball
    |   |-- Basketball
    |   `-- Yoga
```

Comment: Read https://serverfault.com/questions/43014/copying-a-large-directory-tree-locally-cp-or-rsync

Comment: The default rsync on MacOS is version 2.6.9 which is about 16 years old. You might try the homebrew version instead. (I'm not a mac user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this myself ...

rsync --recursive --files-from=<(find /Volumes/GroupFolders -iname '*tennis*' -o -iname '*football*') / /Users/myusername/Desktop/new_folder/